# Добавить pug-шаблон в вёрстку через appenChild и require?

Tags: javascript, webpack, pug

Подключен webpack, создан в  отдельном файле pug элемент, который необходимо добавить в вёрстку.

```
_form.parentNode.appendChild(require('../aboutBlock/aboutBlock.pug'));
```

Почему таким образом оно выдаёт ошибку и как это исправить?

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что можно пихать pug элемент в require? На официальном сайте pug я ничего такого не увидел

Answer (score 0):

Отдельных вьюхи подключаются в `Pug` через `include`:

```
include partials/header
```